# Does Office 365 Preview API provide access to Tasks?

Tags: ms-office, office365

I've already successfully found the task folder using this URL:
https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Folders('Tasks')

Despite this, I can't find any documentation on how to read tasks from this folder. Is this because it is a preview and it will be included in the RTM? Or does someone actually have a way to read the tasks from this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jan Tanis, Tasks are not yet supported through the Rest API. Unfortunately we don't have a timeline on when it will be included.

Comment: Engineering are looking for feedback on this, please submit your need for this on UserVoice at http://aka.ms/OfficeDevFeedback

Comment: Hi Rohit, any news regarding REST for Tasks?

Comment: @OSP sorry for the late reply. This fell through as I was away in dec. Unfortunately, I still don't have a timeline that I can share for tasks.

Comment: @RahulPatil, No, we don't have a timeline yet on when Exchange 'Tasks' might make it to REST API.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a way to access the list of tasks inside task folder.
Use the below url to get the list of tasks from office365

Accessing https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Folders('Tasks') - will return whether any task is present in this folder or not.

By hitting the below url, can fetch the list of tasks
https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Folders('Tasks')/Messages

Hope it helps !

Comment: I've got this result
{
@odata.context: "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/$metadata#Me/Folders('Tasks')/Messages",
value: [ ]
}